# JEdit keeps moving my icons on desktop

Tags: windows-7, jedit

It's weird, really weird.

1. Windows 7 64 bit
2. JEdit 4.4.1
3. Autoarrange on desktop is disabled

Every time I open a .sql file that is on my desktop and I save it from JEdit, the icon of the file is put under the Bin Icon like when autoarrange is on. It just happens with JEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is caused by the two stage save feature (described below), disable it and see if it still happens.

> Two-Stage Save
>
> To prevent data loss in the unlikely case that jEdit should crash in
>   the middle of saving a file, files are first saved to a temporary file
>   named #filename#save#. If this operation is successful, the original
>   file is replaced with the temporary file.
>
> However, in some situations, this behavior is undesirable. For
>   example, on Unix this creates a new i-node so while jEdit retains file
>   permissions, the owner and group of the file are reset, and if it is a
>   hard link the link is broken. The “two-stage save” feature can be
>   disabled in the General pane of the Utilities>Global Options dialog
>   box; see the section called “The General Pane”.
>   http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/saving.html